# Ada fill constant string with Nulls

Tags: string, ada

I want to make a constant string that looks like:

```
My_Null_String : constant String(1 .. 50) := "NULL***********************";
```

with all of the *s being `Ascii.Nul` characters.  It is not possible to do this via the `others` keyword, as in:

```
My_Null_String : constant String(1 .. 50) := "NULL" & (others => Ascii.Nul);
```

Is there an elegant solution to this that doesn't involve a huge block of `Ascii.Nul` characters to fill out the rest of my string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
My_Null_String : constant String(1 .. 50) := "NULL" & (5 .. 50 => ASCII.NUL);
```

The problem with your original attempt is that in order to evaluate

```
(others => ASCII.NUL)
```

the program has to have a way to determine the bounds.  It doesn't, and it's not smart enough to make calculations such as figuring out that this is formed by concatenating two strings and therefore we can figure out that the bounds should be whatever is left over after the first string is evaluated.  The language would have to make a special case just for this (array concatenation), and it doesn't.

Comment: I'd write `My_Null_String'Last` rather than `50`. Actually, that doesn't work; either define a constant with the value 50 and use it, or define `subtype String50 is String(1..50)` and use `String50'Last`. (Perhaps pick a more meaningful name than `String50`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Right, `My_Null_String'Last` isn't legal.  You cannot use the name of a variable in its own declaration.  8.3(16).

Comment: You're right, which I realized as I was writing the comment (thus the "Actually, that doesn't work"). My point, which I should have made more clearly, is that writing the number `50` twice is poor practice. On the other hand, I haven't thought of a way to clean up this particular case without writing a lot of overly verbose code.

Comment: `Null_String: constant String := "NULL"; subtype Padded_String is String(1..50); My_Null_String : constant Padded_String := Null_String & (1..Padded_String'Length-Null_String'Length => ASCII.NUL);` -- Ick

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, that's how I would have done it in a real program.  I was just tryint to get him past his compile problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
My_Null_String : constant String(1 .. 50) := ('N','U','L','L', others => ASCII.Nul);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.
"expected type "Standard Character" found a string type"

Comment: A syntax like `1 .. 4 =>` lets you specify an array element (in this case a `Character`) that all of the elements `1..4` will be set to.  Since they aren't going to be set to the same value, this won't work.  Something like `(1=>'N', 2=>'U', 3..4=>'L', others=>Ascii.Nul)` would work, but it's ugly.

Comment: then My_Null_String : constant String(1 .. 50) := ('N','U','L','L', others => Ascii.Nul);

Comment: I suggest updating your answer to reflect your latest comment.